# How to manage request data on entry file in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

In Node Js, on the entry file e.g. index.js, How can I get requested data either as Form-data or Form-URL-encoded or Raw JSON data in middleware?

In my project, I am handling various API request, 
Few requests contain file type so requesting as form-data.
Few requests do not contain file type so requests are coming as Form-URL-encoded.

Now the main problem is before routing, I need a specific field from req.body in the middleware.
But I am getting req.body as undefined.

For reference here is my index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.raw());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use((req, res, next) => { 
    const routes_handler = require('./routes/index.js')(app, express, req);
    next();
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running at Port " + 3000);
});
```

and the `routes/index.js` file as follows:

```
module.exports = function (app, express, req) {

    console.log(req.body); 
    //I need here data of req.body for all requests type (form data, URL-encoded, raw JSON)

    app.post('/', function (req, res) {
     console.log("Here I can get the requested body easily", req.body)
     res.send('Hello World');
    });

    app.post('*', function (req, res) {
        res.send({
            code: 0,
            message: 'No Content',
            status_code: 204,
            data: {
                error: 'API not found!'
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Also, I know for file type data, POSTMAN will send the request as Form-data, not as Form-url-encoded. So which I should choose `Formidable` or `Multer`?

Comment: You are trying to fetch the body outside the route, this will not be accessible.
If you want to access all of them inside one common function, try using middleware instead.
Can you also add some info on how you are calling `routes/index.js` function>

Comment: I can post an answer on middleware if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: routes/index.js is being called from the entry file index.js, yes you can post your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you get all the data in `index.js` is by creating middlewares for your application, every time any routes that go into your application will be passed through this middleware.

> Middleware functions are functions that have access to the request object (req), the response object (res), and the next function in the application’s request-response cycle. The next function is a function in the Express router which, when invoked, executes the middleware succeeding the current middleware.

The below middleware will simply listen to all routes & adds up request time to request time, here goes the code

```
let express = require('express')
let app = express()
let bodyParser = require("body-parser")
app.use(bodyParser.json())
let requestTime = function (req, res, next) { // simply updating add the requestBody using the middleware
 req.requestTime = Date.now();
 req.json_body = req.body;
 next()
}
app.use(requestTime) // requestTime is the middleware here

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 var responseText = 'Hello World!<br>'
 responseText += '<small>Requested at: ' + req.requestTime + '</small>'
 res.send(responseText)
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Few things to note here

- Always add interceptor above all routes
- Don't forget to add `next()` inside the middleware, else it will not go to the next route.

Now, coming to the second part of your question which is accessing body,formdata, etc

You can use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) npm module to achieve that, [something like this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#expressconnect-top-level-generic)
Starting from [Express 4](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/migrating-4.html), body-parser comes inbuilt with it, so you can try out something

```
app.use(express.json());

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
 })
);
```

Now, the last bit, you don't need [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) for formdata, but for file upload like `multipart/form-data` you will need this. Both are good in their own ways, I would go for [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Nice answer Sunil. I know that middlewares simply listen to all routes. But can you please let me know how can I get req.body in the function requestTime()? OR Is this possible to get requested body parameters in middleware?

Comment: @DeepKakkar I have updated my answer with the adding `bodyParser` and accessing the `req.body` from it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `body-parser` module is your answer.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Add the following line before the routes in your `index.js` after installing the `body-parser` package.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```